# UI Router and Satellizer force login

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router, satellizer

I know this question isn't very specific, but I have no idea how to solve this issue or where I should begin..

I'm using [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for authentication with UI-Router. the problem is I have 2 routes `/sign_in` and `/profile` the `/sign_in` issue a request to the server returning the user info (when successful login)... this `currentUser` info is used all over the application...

the problem is when a user try to go to `/profile` before login, it renders the empty view... how do I enforce user to login first before accessing these "restricted" views ?!

again I know this isn't a specific question but I really don't know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found the answer in this [Github Repo](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission)

the idea is to have role based authentication as discussed in the Repo readme.

so the code for forbidding the unauthorised access to `/profile` would be something like the following

```
  $stateProvider.state("profile", {
    url: "/profile",
    templateUrl: "app/profile/profile.html",
    controller: "ProfileCtrl",
    controllerAs: "user",
    data: {
      permissions: {
        except: ['guest'],
        redirectTo: 'sign_in'
      }
    }
  });
```

given that you defined the `guest` role

```
definePermissions = function(Permission, Identity) {
  Permission.defineRole('guest', function(stateParams) {
    return !Identity.currentUser;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into handling the routechangestart event on UI router, I did something similar.

I think this will give you some clues http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

The key is that you need to create some form of authentication service where you can store the logged in state of the user, and since a service is invoked once (singleton) it is shared across your app (controllers, other services, etc). Then in the routechangestart event handling you can prevent routing to the target page and redirect to login if user is not authenticated.